# Knockout - Update dropdownlist with new list

Tags: knockout.js

Here is my HTML

```
<select id="masterLibrary" data-bind="options: libraries, value: library"></select>
```

In class:

```
libraries: string[];
library: KnockoutObservable<string>;
this.libraries= data.libraries.map(x => x.name);
this.library = getLibraryName(data.libraryId);
```

After changing the city dropdown, I want to update the libraries with the selected city.

```
this.city.subscribe(name => {
    DataService.instance.get('city/' + this.name(), (data): any => {
        this.libraries = data.libraries.map(x => x.name);
    });
});
```

I am getting the data, but UI dropdown is not updating the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because libraries is not an `observableArray` and is just a normal array of strings so any updates will not be reflected on the page.  If that is the case then you will also need to change how you are loading the libraries `observeableArray` when the city changes.

Comment: I tried with Knockoutobservable and it worked. Thanks